# How do I get a Google formkey with the new google forms

Tags: google-forms

The old Google form embed code looked like:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/embeddedform?formkey=dFdXNHV2aGthMW4sdg32enZsd2VkZWc6MQ" height="2200" width="700" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

The new Google form embed code looks like:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1fh95JfDQsElkjfdgLH234PwzA2bGTTwhRs7Tk6Eg/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

I am using a CMS plugin that takes an arbitrary formkey and generates the embed code.

Does anyone know how to get the formkey value using the new Google forms?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an "old" Google form (if you can see a menu bar at the top with "file" in it, then it's an old form), then look in the URL of the edit page for the form.  The hash string appearing before "/edit" seems to work as the formkey.  For example, suppose your edit page's URL is

```
https://docs.google.com/a/forms/d/###formkey_hash/edit
```

and it generates HTML for embedding this form in your website, as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/###embed_hash/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

and in your embedded form, you want the spreadsheet title to be hidden.  You could accomplish this like

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/###embed_hash/viewform?embedded=true&formkey=###formkey_hash&ttl=0" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
```

The ttl=0 pair turns off the title, but this won't work without the formkey pair.

This trick doesn't work for new Google forms, however.  I don't know whether that's because (a) URL parameters don't work for new forms, (b) they do work, but the formkey is found by some other method, or (c) none of the above.

Comment: The asker specifically is asking how to get the formkey on the new Google Forms, Is your answer still relevant? Also this question is 3 years old so there may have been many versions of Forms since then...